# How to properly delete an sqlite DB on a tearDown() in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, sqlite, unit-testing, phpunit

Here's a simplified test with `setUp` and `tearDown` methods:

```
class FooTest extends TestCase
{
    private $dbFile;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->dbFile = 'test.db';

        if (!file_exists($this->dbFile)) {

            $pdo = new \PDO('sqlite:'.$this->dbFile);
            $pdo->query('
                CREATE TABLE `Users` (
                `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                `foo` TEXT
            )');
        }
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        if (file_exists($this->dbFile))
            unlink($this->dbFile);
    }

    public function testFoo()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

This looks fine in theory but I'm getting an `unlink(test.db): Text file busy` error.

Any ideas on how to properly delete an sqlite DB on a `tearDown()` method in PHPUnit?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a SQLite File Data base, you could use the in-memory mode where the 'File' is only ":memory:". That way you do not need to delete the Database file.

Also see: https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

(But I do not know the PHP interface to SQLite.)

Comment: I think that's a good alternative but I found the answer to my question. I need to NULLify the connection so the delete would work.

Answer (score 0):

For those who care, I found the answer to my question:

Simply unset or nullify the PDO connection to "close" it before deleting the SQLite DB.

`unset($this->pdo);` or `$this->pdo = null;`

then proceed with `unlink()`;